# how to get geofense request id in geotrasition service class

Tags: java, android, geofencing

Here i put geofense logic for create,start,remove,clear geofense but i want to get request id to do some task on id when it enter in range
activity

```
// Start Geofence creation process
private void startGeofence() {
    Log.i(TAG, "startGeofence()");
    if( geoFenceMarker != null ) {
        Geofence geofence = createGeofence( geoFenceMarker.getPosition(), GEOFENCE_RADIUS );
        GeofencingRequest geofenceRequest = createGeofenceRequest( geofence );
        addGeofence( geofenceRequest );
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Geofence marker is null");
    }
}

private static final long GEO_DURATION = 60 * 60 * 1000;
private static final String GEOFENCE_REQ_ID = "My Geofence";
private static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 500.0f; // in meters



// Create a Geofence
private Geofence createGeofence( LatLng latLng, float radius ) {
    String uid = uuid.randomuuid().tostring();
    Log.d(TAG, "createGeofence");
    return new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(uid)
            .setCircularRegion( latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, radius)
            .setExpirationDuration( GEO_DURATION )
            .setTransitionTypes( Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                    | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT )
            .build();
}

// Create a Geofence Request
private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest( Geofence geofence ) {
    Log.d(TAG, "createGeofenceRequest");
    return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger( GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER )
            .addGeofence( geofence )
            .build();
}

private PendingIntent geoFencePendingIntent;
private final int GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE = 0;
private PendingIntent createGeofencePendingIntent() {
    Log.d(TAG, "createGeofencePendingIntent");
    if ( geoFencePendingIntent != null )
        return geoFencePendingIntent;

    Intent intent = new Intent( this, GeofenceTrasitionService.class);
    return PendingIntent.getService(
            this, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
}

// Add the created GeofenceRequest to the device's monitoring list
private void addGeofence(GeofencingRequest request) {
    Log.d(TAG, "addGeofence");
    if (checkPermission())
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                googleApiClient,
                request,
                createGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onResult: " + status);
    if ( status.isSuccess() ) {
        saveGeofence();
        drawGeofence();
    } else {
        // inform about fail
    }
}

// Draw Geofence circle on GoogleMap
private Circle geoFenceLimits;
private void drawGeofence() {
    Log.d(TAG, "drawGeofence()");

    if ( geoFenceLimits != null )
        geoFenceLimits.remove();

    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
            .center( geoFenceMarker.getPosition())
            .strokeColor(Color.argb(50, 70,70,70))
            .fillColor( Color.argb(100, 150,150,150) )
            .radius( GEOFENCE_RADIUS );
    geoFenceLimits = map.addCircle( circleOptions );
}

private final String KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT = "GEOFENCE LATITUDE";
private final String KEY_GEOFENCE_LON = "GEOFENCE LONGITUDE";

// Saving GeoFence marker with prefs mng
private void saveGeofence() {
    Log.d(TAG, "saveGeofence()");
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences( Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

    editor.putLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT, Double.doubleToRawLongBits( geoFenceMarker.getPosition().latitude ));
    editor.putLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LON, Double.doubleToRawLongBits( geoFenceMarker.getPosition().longitude ));
    editor.apply();
}

// Recovering last Geofence marker
private void recoverGeofenceMarker() {
    Log.d(TAG, "recoverGeofenceMarker");
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences( Context.MODE_PRIVATE );

    if ( sharedPref.contains( KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT ) && sharedPref.contains( KEY_GEOFENCE_LON )) {
        double lat = Double.longBitsToDouble( sharedPref.getLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT, -1 ));
        double lon = Double.longBitsToDouble( sharedPref.getLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LON, -1 ));
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng( lat, lon );
        markerForGeofence(latLng);
        drawGeofence();
    }
}

// Clear Geofence
private void clearGeofence() {
    Log.d(TAG, "clearGeofence()");
    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(
            googleApiClient,
            createGeofencePendingIntent()
    ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            if ( status.isSuccess() ) {
                // remove drawing
                removeGeofenceDraw();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void removeGeofenceDraw() {
    Log.d(TAG, "removeGeofenceDraw()");
    if ( geoFenceMarker != null)
        geoFenceMarker.remove();
    if ( geoFenceLimits != null )
        geoFenceLimits.remove();
}
```

geotrasition service class

```
public class GeofenceTrasitionService extends IntentService {

private static final String TAG = GeofenceTrasitionService.class.getSimpleName();

public static final int GEOFENCE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;

public GeofenceTrasitionService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    // Handling errors
    if ( geofencingEvent.hasError() ) {
        String errorMsg = getErrorString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode() );
        Log.e( TAG, errorMsg );
        return;
    }

    int geoFenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
    // Check if the transition type is of interest
    if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
            geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT ) {
        // Get the geofence that were triggered
        List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

        String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTrasitionDetails(geoFenceTransition, triggeringGeofences );

        // Send notification details as a String
        sendNotification( geofenceTransitionDetails );
    }
}


private String getGeofenceTrasitionDetails(int geoFenceTransition, List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {
    // get the ID of each geofence triggered
    ArrayList<String> triggeringGeofencesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for ( Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences ) {
        triggeringGeofencesList.add( geofence.getRequestId() );
    }

    String status = null;
    if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER )
        status = "Entering ";
    else if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT )
        status = "Exiting ";
    return status + TextUtils.join( ", ", triggeringGeofencesList);
}

private void sendNotification( String msg ) {
    Log.i(TAG, "sendNotification: " + msg );

    // Intent to start the main Activity
    Intent notificationIntent = MainActivity.makeNotificationIntent(
            getApplicationContext(), msg
    );

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    // Creating and sending Notification
    NotificationManager notificatioMng =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    notificatioMng.notify(
            GEOFENCE_NOTIFICATION_ID,
            createNotification(msg, notificationPendingIntent));

}

// Create notification
private Notification createNotification(String msg, PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_location)
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setContentTitle(msg)
            .setContentText("Geofence Notification!")
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    return notificationBuilder.build();
}


private static String getErrorString(int errorCode) {
    switch (errorCode) {
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
            return "GeoFence not available";
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
            return "Too many GeoFences";
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
            return "Too many pending intents";
        default:
            return "Unknown error.";
    }
}
}
```

when i create geofense i want to put uuid every time i want to createfense and want to retrive that request id in geotransition srevice class

Comment: What is the actual question? What line is not working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: no i am not getting error but i want to get request id which is enter in range if i create geofense 20 times then there are 20 request id and i want to get request id  from that 20 request id which is enter in geofense range

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you want have a Id on your geofence, and be able to get back this Id when an event occur.

if you have several geofence you should set a hasmap (Id,LatLng).
when an event occurs , you can have the location back of this event with:
`LatLng mLocation = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation();`
so now you have the location , you can have the id with your hashmap.
(get the key `Id` for this value `mLocation`)

Answer (score 0):

Other solution, more academic and efficient:
You want to past geofence's information   from activity to your service.
Since you use a service herited from "IntentService" , you should rather pass information why a Messenger.

********In your main activity***********

1. create this a Handler class :

   class ResponseHandler extends Handler {
   @Override
   public void handleMessage(Message message) {
   Bundle extras = message.getData();
   if (extras != null) {
   myidGeofence = extras.getString("mId");
   } else {
   Log.i(TAG, "handleMessage: no extra");
   }
2. use instance of this class and add extra to your intent
   Messenger messenger = new Messenger(new ResponseHandler());
   intent.putExtra("messager",messenger);

********In your service***********

1. get the messenger from the intent and give it back

   Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
   Messenger  messager = (Messenger) extras.get("messager");
   Message msg = Message.obtain();
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   String idGeofence = geofence.getRequestId()
   bundle.putString("mId",  idGeofence);
   msg.setData(bundle);

2)send back the message to your activity

```
try {
 messager.send(msg);
} catch (RemoteException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

more information on Messenger here :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample